# Deploy a WAR (Spring app) to Tomcat, manually through the terminal

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, war, web-deployment

First of all I'd like to thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

So I have created a Maven project with Spring that comes with a demo app. I have successfully run the project on Tomcat (the one that comes bundled with Netbeans) and everything seems to be working just fine.

I am supposed to develop an application in Spring and deploy it to a server with which I can only interface through ssh. In order to simulate that scenario, I've installed a new instance of Tomcat on my local machine. I would like to package the demo webapp in a WAR file and copy it to the new instance of Tomcat, and run it ./startup.sh from there.

However, my brilliant plan failed immediately as I can't locate the WAR file. I ran the application from Netbeans, and browsed through the folder structure of Tomkat (the one that comes with netbeans, lets call it T1) in order to find the WAR file but there is nothing!

So I've come to the point where I can't proceed and I need to turn to the community for assistance.

I guess my set of questions are:

- How can I get the WAR of the app that's been deployed to T1
- After I get the WAR file, can I just go and copy it in the webapps folder of T2 and expect everything to work straight outta the box?

Thank you!

P.S. I am using Tomcat 7

Comment: Did you package the app through `mvn package`? Also make sure your have `<packaging>war</packaging>` in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how it is done in NetBeans, but usually you would in Eclipse(right click->run as->maven install) which is going to create a war file for you in target folder in your project. after that you can deploy that in tomcat (or if you have maven executable you can do it yourself by cding in dir where the pom is and running install command (full reference is here :[maven install](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/)

1) using tomcat manager (localhost:8080/manager/html/list) login in and deploy(straight forward)

2) or take that war file and copy it to webapps folder of the tomcat and if tomcat is set to autodeploy(can be found in server.xml) it will detect it and deploy it.